# custom checkbox react only one to check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this checkbox component!

```
const CheckBox = props =>{
    var [show,setshow] = useState(false);
    const option = props.name.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return(
       <div className="filter-option" onClick={e=>setshow(!show)} data={option}>
          <div className={show?"check-bock checked":"check-bock"} >
              <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
          </div>
          <label className="font-20">{props.name}</label>
       </div>
     )
}
```

The checked class will show checkmark, but if i want to render multiple checkboxes the problem is all checkboxes are checked at once!

I want only one checked and others unchecked!

Comment: The reason is that you use one state to all checkboxes, therefore, it will check all checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to keep in state which checkbox is checked and store this state in parent from where all checkboxes are rendered

```
const CheckBox = props =>{
    const option = props.name.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return(
       <div className="filter-option" onClick={e=>props.setshow(prev => props.name == prev? '': props.name)} data={option}>
          <div className={props.show?"check-bock checked":"check-bock"} >
              <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
          </div>
          <label className="font-20">{props.name}</label>
       </div>
     )
}

const Parent = () => {

    var [show,setshow] = useState('');
    return (
       <>
         <Checkbox name="first" show={"first" === show} setShow={setShow}/>
         <Checkbox name="second" show={"second" === show} setShow={setShow}/>
       </>
    )

}
```

Comment: sorry i didn't understand how u accessing setshow as prop?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to pass the prop. Updated ans